# Create new variable with ifelse() without repeating the original variable using "or" ("|")?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to group the `CPT Code` variable into procedure groups. I have long lists of codes and want to avoid repeating `CPT Code == xxxxx`  in front of every CPT number. If CPT = any of the numbers to the right, name `proc_group` for the appropriate procedure group. The below code turns categorizes everything as `Other` (not true).

Open to `if_else()`, `case_when()` etc but how can we avoid rewriting the original variable?

```
libary(dplyr)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    `CPT Code` = as.numeric(`CPT Code`) ,
    proc_group = ifelse(`CPT Code` ==  ( 48120 | 48140 | 48145 | 48146 | 48148 ) , "Pancreatectomy", 
                        ifelse(`CPT Code` == (44140 | 44141 | 44143 | 44144  ), "Colectomy",
                               ifelse( `CPT Code` == (44155 | 44156 | 44157 | 44158 | 44211  ) , "Proctectomy", 
                               "Other"
                                 )) ))
  
  

tabyl(df$proc_group)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `forcats::fct_collapse()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    proc_group = fct_collapse(
      as.numeric(`CPT Code`),
      "Pancreatectomy" = c(48120, 48140, 48145, 48146, 48148),
      "Colectomy" = c(44140, 44141, 44143, 44144), 
      "Proctectomy" = c(44155, 44156, 44157, 44158, 44211),
      other_level = "Other"
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thanks this got me close. An error said `fct_collapse` only accepts characters or factors, so I turned `CPT Code` into characters and then added `""` around every code within the brackets and it seems to work!